# Splitting a C++ std::string using tokens, e.g. ";"

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to split a string in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string-in-c)

Best way to split a string in C++? The string can be assumed to be composed of words separated by ;

From our guide lines point of view C string functions are not allowed and also Boost is also not allowed to use because of security conecerns open source is not allowed.

The best solution I have right now is:

string str("denmark;sweden;india;us");

Above str should be stored in vector as strings. how can we achieve this?

Thanks for inputs.

Comment: I don't think this should be marked as a duplicate, the other question promotes elegance over efficiency, which I disagree with and avoided for that very reason.

Comment: "[HOW TO SPLIT A STRING IN C++](http://www.martinbroadhurst.com/how-to-split-a-string-in-c.html)" lists few nice alternatives.

Answer (score 255, accepted):

I find [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) is often the simplest. The optional delimiter parameter means it's not just for reading "lines":

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<string> strings;
    istringstream f("denmark;sweden;india;us");
    string s;    
    while (getline(f, s, ';')) {
        cout << s << endl;
        strings.push_back(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great method! Write carefully though. At first I couldn't compile this ... because I had been using double quotes on the delimiter (getline(f, s, ";")). #FeelingStupid.

Comment: Any idea how to split string based on another string? For example, split `"abdecfdcfe"` by the string `"de"` which will return `{"ab", "cfdcfe"}`.
Also any way to split string for multiple characters? Like in the above example, the answer will be `{"ab", "cf", "cf"}`.

Comment: Using for-loop as in `for (string s; getline(f, s, ';'); )` is also nice.

Comment: Simple and great method for normal use. Just some nitpicking for future ref: 1) It is quite slow, better to use a different way if one needs performance. 2) `getline` accepts only `char` as a delimiter(if we use `std::string`). For example, using std::string::find and std::string::substr could be a nice way to address those two shortcomings, and it's very simple as well.

Answer (score 24):

You could use a string stream and read the elements into the vector.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string) are many different examples...

A copy of one of the examples:

```
std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string& s, char seperator)
{
   std::vector<std::string> output;

    std::string::size_type prev_pos = 0, pos = 0;

    while((pos = s.find(seperator, pos)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        std::string substring( s.substr(prev_pos, pos-prev_pos) );

        output.push_back(substring);

        prev_pos = ++pos;
    }

    output.push_back(s.substr(prev_pos, pos-prev_pos)); // Last word

    return output;
}
```

Comment: in the link provided space is used as a seperator how can i specify";" as a seperator

Comment: There are many exampels, some with space seperator and some with a variable seperator

Comment: More examples can be found in this question. http://stackoverflow.com/q/53849/2298

Comment: Accept strings into functions by ref-to-const please!

Comment: Oh, and it's spelt "examples" ;)

Answer (score 11):

There are several libraries available solving this problem, but the simplest is probably to use Boost Tokenizer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

typedef boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char> > tokenizer;

std::string str("denmark;sweden;india;us");
boost::char_separator<char> sep(";");
tokenizer tokens(str, sep);

BOOST_FOREACH(std::string const& token, tokens)
{
    std::cout << "<" << *tok_iter << "> " << "\n";
}
```