# break long string into multiple c++

Tags: c++, string, line

I have a string that is received from third party. This string is actually the text from a text file and it may contain UNIX LF or Windows CRLF for line termination. How can I break this into multiple strings ignoring blank lines? I was planning to do the following, but am not sure if there is a better way. All I need to do is read line by line. Vector here is just a convenience and I can avoid it.
*** Unfortunately I donot have access to the actual file. I only receive the string object ***

```
string textLine;
vector<string> tokens;

size_t pos = 0;
while( true ) {
    size_t nextPos = textLine.find( pos, '\n\r' );
    if( nextPos == textLine.npos )
        break;
    tokens.push_back( string( textLine.substr( pos, nextPos - pos ) ) );
    pos = nextPos + 1;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split a string in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string-in-c)

Comment: Ok, I was over-eager there. This is not a duplicate of that question. My apologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use getline to create new strings based on \n, and then manipulate the line endings.

```
string textLine;
vector<string> tokens;

istringstream sTextLine;
string line;
while(getline(sTextLine, line)) {
  if(line.empty()) continue;
  if(line[line.size()-1] == '\r') line.resize(line.size()-1);
  if(line.empty()) continue;
  tokens.push_back(line);
}
```

EDIT: Use `istringstream` instead of `stringstream`.

Comment: Why `stringstream` instead of `istringstream`?  You're not outputting anything.

Answer (score 6):

You could use `std::getline` as you're reading from the file instead of reading the whole thing into a string.  That will break things up line by line by default.  You can simply not push_back any string that comes up empty.

```
string line;
vector<string> tokens;

while (getline(file, line))
{
    if (!line.empty()) tokens.push_back(line);
}
```

UPDATE:

If you don't have access to the file, you can use the same code by initializing a `stringstream` with the whole text.  `std::getline` works on all stream types, not just files.

Comment: +1 Totally forgot about getline(). May in fact be the best solution.

Comment: Unfortunately I dont have access to the file

Comment: `getline` accepts a single character as the line delimiter (defaults to `\n`). It won't ignore the carriage returns from Windows CRLF.

Comment: @zneak, that's a good point.  [Rob's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126635/break-long-string-into-multiple-c/6126825#6126825) gives a way to strip off a `\r` character.

Comment: You should use `istringstream`, rather than `stringstream`.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the approach given here (std::getline on a std::istringstream)...

[Splitting a C++ std::string using tokens, e.g. ";"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167625/splitting-a-c-stdstring-using-tokens-e-g/5167799#5167799)

... except omit the ';' parameter to std::getline.

Answer (score 1):

A lot depends on what is already present in your toolkit.  I work a lot
with files which come from Windows and are read under Unix, and vice
versa, so I have most of the tools for converting CRLF into LF at hand.
If you don't have any, you might want a function along the lines of:

```
void addLine( std::vector<std::string>& dest, std::string line )
{
    if ( !line.empty() && *(line.end() - 1) == '\r' ) {
        line.erase( line.end() - 1 );
    }
    if ( !line.empty() ) {
        dest.push_back( line );
    }
}
```

to do your insertions.  As for breaking the original text into lines,
you can use `std::istringstream` and `std::getline`, as others have
suggested; it's simple and straightforward, even if it is overkill.
(The `std::istringstream` is a fairly heavy mechanism, since it supports
all sorts of input conversions you don't need.)  Alternatively, you
might consider a loop along the lines of:

```
std::string::const_iterator start = textLine.begin();
std::string::const_iterator end   = textLine.end();
std::string::const_iterator next  = std::find( start, end, '\n' );
while ( next != end ) {
    addLine( tokens, std::string( start, next ) );
    start = next + 1;
    next = std::find( start, end, '\n' );
}
addLine( tokens, std::string( start, end ) );
```

Or you could break things down into separate operations:

```
textLine.erase(
    std::remove( textLine.begin(), textLine.end(), '\r'),
    textLine.end() );
```

to get rid of all of the CR's,

```
std::vector<std:;string> tokens( split( textLine, '\n' ) );
```

, to break it up into lines, where `split` is a generalized function
along the lines of the above loop (a useful tool to add to your
toolkit), and finally:

```
tokens.erase(
    std::remove_if( tokens.begin(), tokens.end(), 
                    boost::bind( &std::string::empty, _1 ) ),
    tokens.end() );
```

.  (Generally speaking: if this is a one-of situation, use the
`std::istringstream` based solution.  If you think you may have to do
something like this from time to time in the future, add the `split`
function to your took kit, and use it.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/).

> Split string into tokens
>
> A sequence of calls to this function
>   split str into tokens, which are
>   sequences of contiguous characters
>   separated by any of the characters
>   that are part of delimiters.

Comment: You could, but I wouldn't.  `strtok` is very easy to misuse.

Comment: Correct. Come to think of it, suggesting `strtok` was a bad advice :-(.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the string in a stringstream and then use the getline method like the previous answer mentioned.  Then, you could just act like you were reading the text in from a file when it really comes from another string.