# spliting in c++ like what we do in c#

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to split a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string-in-c)
>   [Splitting a C++ std::string using tokens, e.g. “;”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167625/splitting-a-c-stdstring-using-tokens-e-g)

think I have this string :

```
string a = "hello,usa,one,good,bad";
```

I want to splitting this string with **,**

so I need a array of string like here :

```
string *a ; a = { hello , usa , one , good , bad }
```

what shoudl I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple AXE parser will do it:

```
std::vector<std::string> strings;
auto split = *(*(axe::r_any() - ',') >> e_push_back(strings));
split(a.begin(), a.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to code this on your own you can do a web search for "c++ tokenize string" and take, for example, a look here: [CPPHOWTO](http://oopweb.com/CPP/Documents/CPPHOWTO/Volume/C++Programming-HOWTO-7.html)

Comment: This should be a comment too!