# Read and split with c++

Tags: c++, split, readfile

With c++ I read a file

```
a;aa a;1 
b;b bb;2
```

and split the lines, with this code

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
vector<string> split(string str, string separator)
{
    int found;
    vector<string> results;
    found = str.find_first_of(separator);
    while(found != string::npos) {
        if(found > 0) {
            results.push_back(str.substr(0,found));
        }
        str = str.substr(found+1);
        found = str.find_first_of(separator);
    }
    if(str.length() > 0) {
        results.push_back(str);
    }
    return results;
}
void lectura()
{
    ifstream entrada;
    string linea;
    vector<string> lSeparada;
    cout << "== Entrada ==" << endl;
    entrada.open("entrada.in");
    if ( entrada.is_open() ) {
        while ( entrada.good() ) {
            getline(entrada,linea);
            cout << linea << endl;
            lSeparada = split(linea,";");
            cout << lSeparada[0] << endl;
        }
        entrada.close();
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

but I get trash in the output

```
== Entrada ==
a;aa a;1
a
b;b bb;2
b

b a;11?E????aa a!(GXG10F????11?GXGb bb;21F????b bb!?G1?F????2??
```

Why do I get this trash?

Comment: Try running your program under valgrind to look for memory access errors.

Comment: For a simpler way to split on ';' have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167625/splitting-a-c-stdstring-using-tokens-e-g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last call to `getline` leaves `linea` empty. With an empty line as input, `split` will return an empty vector (the test `length() > 0` will be false). Trying to dereference the first element (`lSeparada[0]`) then invokes undefined behaviour.

Maybe the input file does not contain an empty line, but the last call to `getline()` will fail. You should test **whether the `istream&` returned by `std::getline()` is good** with `while(getline(entrada,linea))` instead of `while(entrada.good()) getline(entrada,linea)`. This might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

One problem I noticed is that you probably want to use:

```
results.push_back(str.substr(0, found - separator.length()));
```

in `split()` so that the separator string is not included in your output.