# Split the string on dot and retrieve each values from it in C++

Tags: c++, split, stdstring

I need to split the string on `.` in C++..

Below is my string -

`@event.hello.dc1`

Now I need to split on `.` on the above string and retrieve the @event from it and then pass `@event` to the below method -

`bool upsert(const char* key);`

Below is the code I have got so far after reading it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string-in-c) -

```
void splitString() {

    string sentence = "@event.hello.dc1";

    istringstream iss(sentence);
    copy(istream_iterator<string>(iss), istream_iterator<string>(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"));
}
```

But I am not able to understand how to extract `@event` by splitting on `.` using the above method as the above method only works for whitespace... And also how to extract everything from that string by splitting on `.` as mentioned like below -

```
split1 = @event
split2 = hello
split3 = dc1
```

Thanks for the help..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string-in-c

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167625/splitting-a-c-stdstring-using-tokens-e-g

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline):

```
string sentence = "@event.hello.dc1";
istringstream iss(sentence);
std::vector<std::string> tokens;
std::string token;
while (std::getline(iss, token, '.')) {
    if (!token.empty())
        tokens.push_back(token);
}
```

which results in:

```
tokens[0] == "@event"
tokens[1] == "hello"
tokens[2] == "dc1"
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, you *can* change what is considered to be a space for a stream. The approach to do is to replace the `std::ctype<char>` facet in a new `std::locale` and then `imbue()` this newly created `std::locale` into the stream. However, the approach is a bit involved the the task at hand. In fact, to extract the first component of the string separated by a `.` I wouldn't even create a stream:

```
std::string first_component(std::string const& value) {
    std::string::size_type pos = value.find('.');
    return pos == value.npos? value: value.substr(0, pos);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a ctype facet something like this:

```
#include <locale>
#include <vector>

struct dot_reader: std::ctype<char> {
    dot_reader(): std::ctype<char>(get_table()) {}
    static std::ctype_base::mask const* get_table() {
        static std::vector<std::ctype_base::mask> rc(table_size, std::ctype_base::mask());

        rc['.'] = std::ctype_base::space;
        rc['\n'] = std::ctype_base::space; // probably still want \n as a separator?
        return &rc[0];
    }
};
```

Then imbue your stream with an instance of it, and read strings:

```
istringstream iss(sentence);

iss.imbue(locale(locale(), new dot_reader())); // Added this

copy(istream_iterator<string>(iss), 
     istream_iterator<string>(), 
     ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"));
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use the strtok function : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok
You can use by doing something like this :

```
 strtok(sentence.c_str(), ".");
```

Comment: You should mention that `strtok` overwrites the string you pass in.  And that you can't pass the result of `c_str()`, which is `const char*`, to `strtok`, which requires a non-`const`.