# Split the string on dot and extract all the fields from it in C++?

Tags: c++, string, split, char

I am trying to split my actual key on dot and then extract all the fields from after splitting it on dot.

My key would look like something this -

```
@event.1384393612958.1136580077.TESTING
```

Currently, I am able to extract only the first field which is `@event` after splitting it on the dot. Now how to extract all the other fields as well. Below is my code, I am using currently to extract the first field from it.

```
if (key)
{
    char* first_dot = strchr(key, '.');
    if (first_dot)
    {
        // cut at the first '.' character
        first_dot[0] = 0;
    }
}

cout << "Fist Key: " << key << endl;
```

And then after extracting individual fields, store the second field as `uint64_t`, third field as `uint32_t` and last field as `string`.

**Update:-**

This is what I have got now -

```
if (key)
{
char *first_dot = strtok(key, ".");
char *next_dot = strtok(NULL, ".");

uint64_t secondField = strtoul(next_dot, 0, 10);

cout << first_dot << endl;
cout << secondField << endl;

}
```

From which I am able to extract first and second field. What about third and fourth field?

Comment: "Extracting" fields is one thing, but what do you want to do with the result? Store somewhere?

Comment: oops sorry yes, store it somewhere.. let me update the question..

Comment: Then it's a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/237280/912757

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`strtok`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html) instead. `strtok` does exactly, what you're doing right now. It splits the string, when it encounters a delimiting character

```
if (key) {
    char *first_dot = strtok(key, ".");
    ...
    char *next_dot = strtok(NULL, ".");
}
```

The conversion to some `int` type can be done with [`strtoul/strtoull`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtoul.3.html)

```
uint64_t i = strtoul(next_dot, 0, 10);
```

Comment: thanks for example. Now I am wondering how to extract individual fields form it? Pardon my ignorance in C++.. I recently started working with it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you mean with extracting fields? With `first_dot` or `next_dot`, you already have access to the first and second field.

Comment: I see.. now it makes sense and now I am able to extract first and second field.. I updated my question with the code that I am using now.. Similarly I need to extract third and fourth fields as well?

Comment: This is explained at the link/manual to strtok. In the first call, you give the string to parse. In all following calls, you pass NULL as the first argument, until strtok returns NULL (no more tokens).

Comment: And also, it's a silly question, but thought to ask you - should I be splitting the string like the way I am doing currently or should I use the method described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5167799/819916) by using `istringstream` ?

Comment: This (my) answer is more C-like. This means it works with C-strings, when you use `char*`. When you have C++ `std::string`s instead, it's better to use a C++ method like the one in the other answer.