# Debugger says I have uninitialized variables

Tags: c, initialization, valgrind

After hours and hours of searching, I became desperate because I just fail to find uninitialized reads that I apparantly have, according to Valgrind and Dr. Memory, so I'll ask here for help. I used the Code Blocks' debugger and its variable watch, but all I saw there was everything going smoothly and as planned.

```
#define ADRESA "adressbook.txt"

struct Adress
{
    char name[31], lastname[31], email[48], major[10];
    int year;
};

int read(struct Adresa array[])
{
    char temp_line[121];
    int i = 0, j, c = 0;
    FILE* adressbookf = fopen(ADRESA, "r");
    if (adressbookf != NULL)
    {
        printf("File successfully loaded.\n")

        while (fgets(temp_line, 121, adressbookf) != NULL && strlen(temp_line) > 0)
        {
            j = 0;
            c = 0;
            while (temp_line[c] != ',' && c < strlen(temp_line))
            {
                array[i].name[j] = temp_line[c];
                ++j;
                ++c;
            }
            ++c;
            array[i].name[j] = '\0';
            j = 0;

            while (temp_line[c] != ',' && c < strlen(temp_line))
            {
                array[i].lastname[j] = temp_line[c];
                ++j;
                ++c;
            }

            ++c;
            array[i].lastname[j] = '\0';
            j = 0;

            while (temp_line[c] != ',' && c < strlen(temp_line))
            {
                array[i].email[j] = temp_line[c];
                ++j;
                ++c;
            }

            ++c;
            array[i].email[j] = '\0';
            j = 0;

            while (temp_line[c] != ',' && c < strlen(temp_line))
            {
                array[i].major[j] = temp_line[c];
                ++j;
                ++c;
            }

            ++c;
            array[i].year = temp_line[c] - 48;
            ++i;
        }
        fclose(adressbookf);
        return i;
    }
    else return 0;

}

int main()
{
    int number_of_elements = 0;
    struct Adress adressbook[1000];
    printf("Welcome.\n");
    number_of_elements = read(adressbook);

...
```

Apparently, the lines with error are 32, 43 and 54 (Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)).

The file looks something like this:

> name,lastname,nlastname1@x.com,EE,1
>
> john,doe,jdoe1@x.com,AA,1

And it usually ends with a trailing line containing '\n' (but the file doesn't necessarily exists).

I have one more error in the program, but I'd have to copy the whole program here. I hope that one will be resolved with this.

If someone would willing to compile it and examine it that way, I'll be happy to post it.

Here's the error message from Valgrind:

> Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)    at
>   0x4010F1: ucitaj (bs_test_2366.c:156)    by 0x40192E: _main
>   (bs_test_2366.c:255)    by 0x4021EE: main (bs_test_2366.c:385)
>
> Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)    at
>   0x4011AD: ucitaj (bs_test_2366.c:167)    by 0x40192E: _main
>   (bs_test_2366.c:255)    by 0x4021EE: main (bs_test_2366.c:385)
>
> Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)    at
>   0x401269: ucitaj (bs_test_2366.c:178)    by 0x40192E: _main
>   (bs_test_2366.c:255)    by 0x4021EE: main (bs_test_2366.c:385)

Note that lines 156, 167 are 178 the first, second and the third

```
while (temp_line[c] != ',' && c < strlen(temp_line))
```

respectively. 255 is the line where the function is called, and 385 is outside of my program.

Comment: If the debugger says "uninitialized variable" and gives you the exact line of the error,what more do you need?

Comment: This is the first time in my life getting in contact with a memory debugger such as Valgrind.
With "fgets(temp_line, 121, adressbookf) != NULL && strlen(temp_line) > 0" in the outer while and with c < strlen(line) I basically abort reading when I reach the end of line or the file. I thought someone with more experience could read it somewhat easilly, because I just can't see where could I possibly touch something uninitialized in those lines.

Comment: While I see various problems with your code - the main question is: Why are you not simply using fscanf or at least strtok(_r)?

Comment: You should use `sizeof(temp_line)` instead of 121

Comment: Andreas; I thought this is simpler because of the trailing '\n' and the commas in the file.

Comment: without a file it runs ok. Paste the file on pastebin and I will run the  program. Post the link as a comment.

Comment: bolov: here's the complete program with the file at the end: http://pastebin.com/NdUtPfNQ

Comment: it runs fine (the short version from the question) with the file.

Comment: can you compile the complete program? I don't see why would one work and the second would not.

Comment: Probably not related to your problem, but in the nested conditions, you should probably use `temp_line[c] != '\0'`, rather than `c < strlen(temp_line)`.  It's both more idiomatic, and a lot more efficient.  (Most idiomatic, of course, would be to use pointers, rather than indices.)  And your code is pure C; you should remove the C++ tag

Comment: the full program runs and then asks for some kind of input. On an unrelated note I just noticed that you copy to the fields of `Adress` without checking you don't step outside of the buffers. (e.g. you copy to the `email` filed and don't check you don't copy  more than `48` characters. Also don't copy char by char. Use `strcpy` (but again make sure you don't overflow.

Comment: Perhaps this might be rewritten with fscanf or something? I tried parsing it with fscanf(adresarf, "%s[^,]", adresbook.name) but it wasn't a success.

Comment: Bolov: well, if you have Valgrind or Dr Memory or something like that installed, you can easily recreate the error.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your error. As I said the program runs on my system. Beyond that I think it is not my job to check your homework.

Comment: Please make sure that your code compiles without warnings before posting it (unless the question is about failing to understand why the code doesn't compile).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69029/discussion-on-question-by-bane-bojanic-debugger-says-i-have-uninitialized-variab).

Answer (score 1):

I see a possible problem. In the first line you index with `c` before you check the range.

```
        while (temp_line[c] != ',' && c < strlen(temp_line))
        {
            array[i].name[j] = temp_line[c];
            ++j;
            ++c;
        }
```

try writing it like this:

```
        while (c < strlen(temp_line) && temp_line[c] != ',')
        {
            array[i].name[j] = temp_line[c];
            ++j;
            ++c;
        }
```

Comment: Oh, you noticed it well but unfortunately it didn't help. What confuses me is that c should never be >= than line length, because I used simple examples, but the debugger still crashes-

Comment: On the contrary. If `c == strlen(temp_line) - 1` then you enter the while loop, `c` gets increased, becomes equal to `strlen(temp_line)` and at the check of the loop condition the index goes out of range.

Comment: Is there a good way to rewrite this to just parse the text file with fscanf?

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167625/splitting-a-c-stdstring-using-tokens-e-g) question. I beleive you can simplify your code using this.

Comment: I need to do it in C.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Read this then: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210528/split-string-with-delimiters-in-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210528/split-string-with-delimiters-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
char temp_line[121]="";
```

Then `temp_line` will be initialized.