# extract opengl version from version string

Tags: c++, opengl

Im trying to get the current opengl verson.

`glGetString(GL_VERSION)` returns

`"4.6.0 NVIDIA 391.01"`

```
    std::string strVersion = (const char*)glGetString(GL_VERSION);
    strVersion = strVersion.substr(0, strVersion.find(" "));
    float number = std::atof(strVersion.c_str());
```

float number = 4.59999990

why is the float not 4.6.0?

Comment: First, "4.6.0" is not a valid number. You can't have two decimal points in numbers. Second, floating-point values are not exact.

Comment: Since when do real numbers have two decimal dots?

Comment: if i change to `strVersion.substr(0, 3)` so string is "4.6" the float number is still `4.59999990`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why you don't get the third number**

`std::atof` will take as many characters as it can that represent a *decimal number*. That's `4.6`. The next dot cannot be part of the number, because there is no such thing as a decimal number with two dots. Decimal numbers only have one dot, separating the *integer* and the *fractional parts*.

**Why you get 4.59999990 instead of 4.6**

Because *floating point numbers* cannot store any possible combination of *integer* and *fractional part*. They have limited space to store information, so they always are just approximations. See [is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

**How to get the version**

*A version is not a number.* That version consists of three numbers, not one: `4`, `6` and `0`. They are *integers*, not *decimal numbers*. So you need to either just handle the version as a string:

```
if (strVersion == "4.6.0")
```

or you have to split it into three parts and get those integer values separately. See [Splitting a C++ std::string using tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167625/splitting-a-c-stdstring-using-tokens-e-g) for how to do that.