# Get date, month and year value from Date string

Tags: c++

I want to get the date, month and year information from the string.

Example Date String: Thu, 30 Jul 2020 00:51:08 -0700 (PDT)

PDT here is for Pacific Daylight time. This string offset (-0700) can change based on system timezone when the file was created.

I need to write a c++ program to extract date, month and year from this string.

Any thoughts on how to go about this?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: If your string has a regular format, you could use a [regular expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) (regex) to parse it.

Comment: I recommend using the `std::string` methods `find` and `substr`, as well as conversion functions.  Another alternative is to use `std::istringstream` and treat the string as a stream.

Comment: personally I would split the string using a space delmiter and start from there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167625/splitting-a-c-stdstring-using-tokens-e-g

Comment: if you have boost in your project then you can use the tokeniser feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a story of evolution.  The correct answer greatly depends on your current toolset (how modern it is).  And even if it is *completely* modern, there are still better tools coming.

### Homo habilis

In C++98 we could stand upright.  And we had tools to scan `int`s out of arrays of `char`s.  `scanf` was the tool to do this.  This result was not type safe, but we could scan ints and strings and then reinterpret those values as the components of a date:  year, month and day.  This might look something like this:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;

    string s = "Thu, 30 Jul 2020 00:51:08 -0700 (PDT)";
    char const* months[] = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
                            "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};
    char wd[4] = {};
    int d;
    char mon[4] = {};
    int y;
    sscanf(s.c_str(), "%s %d %s %d", wd, &d, mon, &y);
    int m;
    for (m = 0; m < 12; ++m)
        if (strcmp(months[m], mon) == 0)
            break;
    ++m;
    cout << y << '\n';
    cout << m << '\n';
    cout << d << '\n';
}
```

This outputs:

```
2020
7
30
```

*Notes:*

- The `" 00:51:08 -0700 (PDT)"` is never even parsed.  It *could* be parsed.  But it is a lot more work.
- There's no error checking.  This might be a valid date or might not.
- There's no type safety.  The results are just `int`s and if you mix them up, it's a run-time error, not a compile-time error.

### Neanderthal

Using C++98, there's also a popular **but** *non-standard* solution:  `strptime`.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;

    string s = "Thu, 30 Jul 2020 00:51:08 -0700 (PDT)";
    tm tm;
    strptime(s.c_str(), "%a, %d %b %Y %T", &tm);
    cout << tm.tm_year + 1900 << '\n';
    cout << tm.tm_mon + 1 << '\n';
    cout << tm.tm_mday << '\n';
    cout << tm.tm_hour << '\n';
    cout << tm.tm_min << '\n';
    cout << tm.tm_sec << '\n';
}
```

`strptime` is in the POSIX standard, but not in the C or C++ standards.  It is also supported by MS Visual Studio.  So it is a popular extension.  And with good reason.  It is much higher level, and puts the results into a `struct tm`:  A type representing a date/time; the beginnings of type safety.

Output:

```
2020
7
30
0
51
8
```

There are still some problems:

- `" -0700 (PDT)"` is never parsed.  There's no way to ask `strptime` to do this.
- There are weird and inconsistent offsets on the different fields of `tm`.  For example the month is zero-based and the day is one-based.  But at least it knows how to parse the time too, and relatively easily.
- Error checking is there but easy to ignore.  `strptime` returns `NULL` if something bad happens.

### Cro-Magnon

With C++11 arrived an actual C++ wrapper around `strptime` that was officially recognized by the C++ standard with `std::get_time`:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;

    string s = "Thu, 30 Jul 2020 00:51:08 -0700 (PDT)";
    istringstream in{s};
    in.exceptions(ios::failbit);
    tm tm;
    in >> get_time(&tm, "%a, %d %b %Y %T");
    cout << tm.tm_year + 1900 << '\n';
    cout << tm.tm_mon + 1 << '\n';
    cout << tm.tm_mday << '\n';
    cout << tm.tm_hour << '\n';
    cout << tm.tm_min << '\n';
    cout << tm.tm_sec << '\n';
}
```

With a C++ wrapper you can parse from streams, which gives you access to throwing an exception on parse failure.  But it is still a simple wrapper and so the result is just a `tm`.  This has the same weirdness as the previous solution.

The output is the same as in the previous solution:

```
2020
7
30
0
51
8
```

### Homo sapiens

Though the strongly typed `std::chrono` `time_point` / `duration` system was introduced in C++11, it is not until C++20 that it is integrated with the civil calendar, gaining `get_time`-like functionality, and going far beyond that.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    string s = "Thu, 30 Jul 2020 00:51:08 -0700 (PDT)";
    istringstream in{s};
    in.exceptions(ios::failbit);
    local_seconds t;
    in >> parse("%a, %d %b %Y %T %z (%Z)", t);
    auto td = floor<days>(t);
    year_month_day ymd{td};
    hh_mm_ss hms{t-td};
    cout << ymd << ' ' << hms << '\n';
    cout << ymd.year() << '\n';
    cout << ymd.month() << '\n';
    cout << ymd.day() << '\n';
    cout << hms.hours() << '\n';
    cout << hms.minutes() << '\n';
    cout << hms.seconds() << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
2020-07-30 00:51:08
2020
Jul
30
0h
51min
8s
```

The first thing to notice is the *much* stronger type-safety.  No longer is there a need to convert everything to `int`s to print it out.  And no longer is it necessary to convert to `int`s to do other operations such as arithmetic and comparison.

For example `ymd.year()` has type `std::chrono::year`, not `int`.  If necessary, one can explicitly convert between these two representations.  But it is generally unnecessary, and akin to a risky `reinterpret_cast`.

There are no longer unintuitive biases such as 1900, or zero-based counts in unexpected places.

Output generally includes the units for easier debugging.

The `" -0700 (PDT)"` *is* parsed here!  These values are not used in the results, but they must be there, else there is a parse error.  And if you want to get these values, they are available with very simple changes:

```
string abbrev;
minutes offset;
in >> parse("%a, %d %b %Y %T %z (%Z)", t, abbrev, offset);
...
cout << offset << '\n';
cout << abbrev << '\n';
```

Now the output includes:

```
-420min
PDT
```

If you need the fields in UTC, instead of in local time, that is one simple change:

```
sys_seconds t;
```

instead of:

```
local_seconds t;
```

Now the offset is subtracted from the parsed time point to result in a UTC time_point (a `std::chrono::time_point` based on `system_clock`) instead and the output changes to:

```
2020-07-30 07:51:08
2020
Jul
30
7h
51min
8s
```

This allows you to easily parse local times plus offset directly into `system_clock::time_point`.

Though not shipping yet (as I write this), vendors *are* working on implementing this.  And in the meantime you can get this functionality with a [free, open-source, header-only C++20 `<chrono>` preview library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) that works with C++11/14/17.  Just add `#include "date/date.h"` and `using namespace date;` and everything just works.  Though with C++11/14 you will need to substitute `hh_mm_ss<seconds> hms{t-td};` for `hh_mm_ss hms{t-td};` (lack of [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction)).

Comment: Using the approach mentioned in Homo Sapiens. I get the following error in VS 2013. After including the latest version of the date.h file. 
Error 1 error C2059: syntax error : '}' 
Error 2 error C2059: syntax error : '}' 
Error 3 error C1075: end of file found before the left angle-bracket '<' at 'c:\date-master\include\date\date.h(3871)' was matched

Comment: I tried it with VS 2019. It just worked fine. 

Would it be possible to get the below result in VS 2013 by not using the open-source library(date.h) as my current work doesn't allow me to upgrade above VS 2013?  

2020-07-30 07:51:08
2020
Jul
30
7h
51min
8s

Comment: Is this the line the _first_ error is reported on: https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/blob/master/include/date/date.h#L3871 ?

Comment: Error 1 : Line Number 3829.

Comment: Error 2: Line Number 7942

Comment: On this line: https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/blob/master/include/date/date.h#L3689 Could you try putting in some `()` like so:  `(w < 19)`?  If that works for you, I'll push it to master.

Comment: It didn't work. Well, with VS 2019. It works just fine without any change. The problem is only when I use it with VS 2013.

Comment: My best guess is that somewhere in here: https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/blob/master/include/date/date.h#L3676-L3828 VS 2013 is interpreting some `<` as an "open-template-paramter-list" instead of as a "less-than".  If you can find that spot, I'll fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <time.h>
char *strptime(const char *buf, const char *format, struct tm *tm);
```

Comment: if you need to write a program you can do it many different ways, but as Jesper mentioned, regex would be very helpful for parsing it.

Comment: @GenoC:  Synopsis of `<ctime>`: http://eel.is/c++draft/ctime.syn  ... oops, no `strptime` there...

Comment: @HowardHinnant, sorry that was my fault. Pretty dumb comment .

Comment: No worries @GenoC.  Is it time yet for me to plug `std::chrono::parse` in C++20? ;-)

Comment: @HowardHinnant, indeed!