# Overloading >> operator to read file

Tags: c++, overloading

Hello I have a problem with separating input data from the file. I want it to be separated with some kind of delimiter instead of space.
Data in file are represented like this:

```
street;num
street;num
...
```

Adress structure:

```
struct adress
{
    std::string street;

    int num;
};
```

```
std::istream &operator>> (std::istream &in, adress &adr)
{
    in>>adr.street >>adr.num;

    return in;
}
```

Comment: I answered to similar problem a few h ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69927761/4165552

Comment: You could read it into a `string` with the existing `operator>>`. Then, find the `;` and separate the substring before and after.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/how-can-i-read-and-parse-csv-files-in-c

Comment: The slightly misnamed `std::getline` takes a "line separator" argument, which can be any character you want.