# is there any way to pass multiple arguments in a class just by using a single string variable in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to take in a lot of data from multiple files and I use getline() to take the entire line to put it into a temporary string value and turn the data from the line into an object(everything is already sorted).

```
void charts(vector<Song> &data, int menuop){
  ifstream stream;
  if(menuop == 1){
    stream.open("charts_top50_1960_1980.csv");
    assert(stream.fail() == false);
    data.clear();
  }
  else if(menuop == 2){
    stream.open("charts_top50_1981_2000.csv");
    assert(stream.fail() == false);
    data.clear();
  }
  else if(menuop == 3){
    stream.open("charts_top50_2001_2020.csv");
    assert(stream.fail() == false);
    data.clear();
  }
  string tempstring;
  while(getline(stream, tempstring)){
    for(int i = 0; i < tempstring.length(); i++){
      if(tempstring[i] == '/'){
        tempstring[i] == ',';
      }
    }
    //cout << tempstring << endl;
    Song tempsong(const &tempstring);
    data.push_back(tempsong);
  }
  stream.close();
}
```

Comment: Answer for the title: Yes. `std::string` in C++ can store arbitrary sequences of bytes (including ones that contain 0x00), so any data (including combinations of multiple values) that can be represented as a file can be represented as a string variable (unless it is too large to fit into the RAM)
.

Comment: I would avoid putting binary data into `std::string`, and prefer `std::vector<char>` instead -- it's more fit for purpose.  `std::string` implies something that is printable.

Comment: Response was to the first comment which suggested `std::string` is great for anything.

Comment: Information can be encoded into a string, and then the function can parse that string to retrieve the information.    That makes a few sacrifices (time to encode data into the string or decode data from it, error detection and handling [e.g. if some required information is omitted from the passed string] must be performed at run time not compile time).

Answer (score 1):

Simply change:

`Song tempsong(const &tempstring);`

to:

`Song tempsong(tempstring);`

And then make sure `Song` has a constructor that takes a `const string&` parameter. Then you can have that constructor split the `string` on `','` characters and use the substrings as needed. There are plenty of other questions on StackOverflow that explain how to do that, for instance:

[Parse (split) a string in C++ using string delimiter (standard C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265581/)

[Splitting a C++ std::string using tokens, e.g. ";"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167625/)

[How do I iterate over the words of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/)

Just to point out a few.